# Select a record from multiple with preference hierarchy from spark dataframe or sql

Tags: sql, oracle, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of products with same product having different categories. I want select only one record based on hierarchy like

```
Product ID.  Category.  Status
1.           Cat1.      status1
1.           Cat2.      status1
1.           Cat3.      status1
2.           Cat1.      status1
2.           Cat2.      status1
3.           Cat2.      status1
```

If record with Cat1 exists, pick it else pick Cat2. If Cat2 doesn't exist pick Cat3. But pick only one out of multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed below solution with the help of answers by Yogesh and Lamansa

```
 val df1 = df.withColum("row_num", when($"category"==="Cat1", "A"),
    .when($"category" ==== "Cat2", "B"),
    .when($"category" === "Cat3", "C"))

    df1.join(df1.groupBy("product_id).agg(first("category").as("category")), 
    Seq("product_id","category")).show
```

When is used as order by category cannot make sure your preferences will be in desired orrder. E.g. Cat2 can be a first preference.

```
Output :
+----------+--------+-------+
|Product ID|Category| Status|
+----------+--------+-------+
|         1|    Cat1|status1|
|         2|    Cat1|status1|
|         3|    Cat2|status1|
+----------+--------+-------+
```

Output :

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number () over (partition by productid order by category) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

If categories are different named then use `case` expression

```
order by (case when category = 'category_x' then 1 
               when category = 'category_gg' then 2 
               else 3 
         end)
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh for prompt response. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same answer with @Yogesh Sharma by using the dataframe functions.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("Product ID").orderBy("Category")
df.withColumn("row", row_number.over(w))
  .filter($"row" === 1)
  .orderBy("Product ID")
  .drop("row")
  .show
```

or use `groupBy` and self-join such as

```
df.join(df.groupBy("Product ID").agg(first("Category").as("Category")), Seq("Product ID", "Category")).show
```

where those will give you the result:

```
+----------+--------+-------+
|Product ID|Category| Status|
+----------+--------+-------+
|         1|    Cat1|status1|
|         2|    Cat1|status1|
|         3|    Cat2|status1|
+----------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your categories are the `cat1., cat2., ... cat10., ...cat100.,....`

You must fetch the number from categories then order them accordingly.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
            T.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY PRODUCTID
                ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(CATEGORY, '[0-9]+'))
            ) AS RN
        FROM YOUR_TABLE T
    )
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Cheers!!